# How do I fix BIOS errors and Kernel panics when booting up?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, lenovo, bios

How do I fix BIOS errors and Kernel panics when booting up? The laptop boots up successfully, but takes a little longer than it might with all of the errors.

[Found at the bottom in this post] are some screen shots being representational of the issue.
Note: if you don't have access to the screenshots, here is a sample:
"BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object" and "Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog"
Repetitions of the past two phrases six times.
"Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)" and "end Kernal panic - not..."

Note: command line has not finished processing/executing visual effects/framework (conceptual-psychology like 'framework', I mean) in the picture there.

Notes about this theoretical-conceptual environment here and now: Ubuntu (dual-boot (on a partitioned Samsung SSD)) on a Windows 11 Lenovo Thinkbook 15-IIL.

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjG4j.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE6Vk.jpg

Comment: Have you checked for any BIOS updates yet?  A lot of times this is something that a vendor bios patch can fix.  Note though that the BIOS Error bugs are not necessarily an indicator of the problem, while the hard failures are about the drive not being able to boot.  however, if this is a theoretical non-real environment, though, then this question is not going to be answerable within the scope of the site

Comment: @ThomasWard, 
The Lenovo Vantage app says everything (BIOS, drivers, and other software) is up to date. 
I also posted on forms.lenovo.com: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/How-do-I-fix-BIOS-errors-and-Kernel-panics-when-booting-up/m-p/5167049